# Count ordered pairs of disjoint subsets having sum greater than K.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, programming

You are given an array A[] having N elements and a number K. I have to count ordered pairs of disjoint non-empty subsets each having a sum greater than K.

For example,

> N=3 and K=5
>
> A = {3, 4, 7}

Then the solution will be 2.
i.e, ({3,4}, {7}) and ({7}, {3,4})

How can I solve this optimally?

Comment: Can you show us some algorithm you came up with, so that we know what we have to beat?

Comment: Let $S$ be the sum of all elements of $A$. I would first list all subsets having a sum greater than $K$ and smaller than $S - K$. Then, you look at the number of ordered pairs $(X, Y)$ of elements from that list that satisfy $X \cap Y = \emptyset$.